# How can I draw a string so that each character will be of the same size?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(SpielField[i], 
         new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 20, FontStyle.Regular),
         new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 650-(i+2)*40);
}
```

Here is my code and here is the definiton:

```
SpielField = new string[column];
```

[image]

This image contains my desired outlook however my output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: [Monospaced Font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: Why draw it column-by-column? Why not build the _whole_ string in memory and use just one single `DrawString` call?

Comment: BTW: Not disposing resources like `Font` and `Brush` will result in resource/memory leaks.

Comment: The only way to force that manually is to determine in advance the maximum width of all characters in your string, and then draw them manually, character by character, spaced out according to that maximum width. But, yes, using a monospace font is so much easier.